# Melhor maneira de fazer Schedule PHP

Tags: php, push-notification, cron

Bom Dia, Pessoal

Tenho um painel PUSH GSM para envio de notificações de apps android já está funcionando perfeitamente, porém agora surgiu a necessidade de fazer uma agendamento das mensagens push.

Pensei em fazer uma rotina que fica verificando a cada 30 segundos se tem um registro com a data de envio menor ou igual a data de agora, em seguida fazer cadastro na tarefa CRON do Cpanel.

Essa seria a melhor alternativa?

Gostaria que tivesse as mesmas opções do Cron, agendando um evento agora ou repetindo de acordo com a configuração pré-estabelecida.

Sabem se já tem alguma coisa assim pronta?

Answer (score 3):

Agendamentos para PHP através do CRON (crontab) é a forma como eu utilizo já há algum tempo, e sem dores de cabeça.

Não posso afirmar se há alguma forma melhor, talvez até tenha, mas posso afirmar que os agendamentos em PHP chamados através do CRON funcionam bem.

Lembre-se que a definição de intervalo será definida no CRON e não no SCRIPT.

Para seguir suas configurações padrão do PHP, é importante informar na linha do CRON o caminho do seu arquivo `php.ini`.

```
php -c /etc/php/php.ini /path/seu_script.php
```